# Number out or number Crystal Report / vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have made an app where i print some reports.

Lets say I'll set 2 reports to be printed: first report will print 1 out of 2 and on the second 2 out of 2.

I guess you have to use a loop or anything similar. Any help? Thanks in advance.

```
`` 
     Dim paramField12 As New ParameterField()
     Dim discreteVal12 As New ParameterDiscreteValue()

     paramField12.ParameterFieldName = "Pallets"
     Dim str12 As String = lblMikos.Text.ToString
     discreteVal12.Value = str12
     paramField12.CurrentValues.Add(discreteVal12)
     paramFields.Add(paramField12)

     crViewer.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields
     crViewer.ReportSource = report
     report.PrintToPrinter(Me.txtSumPallets.Text.ToString, False, 0, 0)
```

Thats the way i pass data from the form to my report so i want from the 12th field to count the pages depens on the SumPallets and print 1 out of 2 , 2 out of 2!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Updated with code.
I've tried ..

``  dim i as integer
     dim c as integer
     c = txtSumPallets.text.tostring
     for i=0 to c 
      paramField12.ParameterFieldName = "Pallets"
     Dim str12 As String = i+1
     discreteVal12.Value = str12
     paramField12.CurrentValues.Add(discreteVal12)
     paramFields.Add(paramField12)
     next
``
But it doesnt work